# I want to add checkpoint to my progress graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qcxvq.jpg)The below code is working fine. I just want to add some checkpoint in the below progress chart.

```
var pie=d3.layout.pie()
.value(function(d){return d})
.sort(null);
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/adeveloperdiary/pen/VaQRqe?editors=0010)

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive about your question?

Comment: there should be a line at 10% progress.

Comment: i have uploaded the picture of what i need